# Python logging - excluding submodule

Tags: python, logging

I have a python **main** which users various submodules.
structure is like this:

```
root:.
│   main.py
│
└───MyModule
        file1.py
        file2.py
        special.py
```

MyModule outputs some important logs (each file does logger = logging.getLogger(**name**) ). However - "special.py" logs need to be stored  separately.

I attempt:

```
MyModuleHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('MyModule.log', maxBytes= 5000000, backupCount=5)
MyModuleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
MyModuleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


specialHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('special.log', maxBytes= 5000000, backupCount=5)
specialHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
specialHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.getLogger('MyModule.special').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('MyModule.special').addHandler(specialHandler)

logging.getLogger('MyModule').addHandler(console)
logging.getLogger('MyModule').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('MyModule').addHandler(MyModuleHandler)
```

guys, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.
This was really silly
All i needed was to set the propagate field in the specified logger.

correct code should be:

```
MyModuleHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('MyModule.log', maxBytes= 5000000, backupCount=5)
MyModuleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
MyModuleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


specialHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('special.log', maxBytes= 5000000, backupCount=5)
specialHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
specialHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.getLogger('MyModule.special').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('MyModule.special').addHandler(specialHandler)
logging.getLogger('MyModule.special').propagate = False

logging.getLogger('MyModule').addHandler(console)
logging.getLogger('MyModule').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('MyModule').addHandler(MyModuleHandler)
```